# Symfony 1 upgrade to Symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have symfony 1 project, and I am planning to upgrade to 2.8.

I am using the bundle [IngewikkeldWrapperBundle](https://github.com/Ingewikkeld/IngewikkeldWrapperBundle)
At step 4 the manual instructs to to Enable the bundle in app/AppKernel.php using:

```
$bundles = array(
     // ...
     new Ingewikkeld\WrapperBundle\IngewikkeldWrapperBundle(),
 );
```

but there is no AppKernel.php in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file was in Symfony 2.8 and not in 1 .
the doc that was provided is not clear